# Overriding default env settings for TokensRegex in stanford

Tags: stanford-nlp

What is the setting to over ride `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation` to 
`edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation`
when token regex rules are added.

Sample example:

`#123456` is tagged as MONEY in Stanford hence to over ride the NER behavior I wrote the the rule which tags `123456` as NUMBER instead of MONEY. As a side effect following `£20.49` is now being tagged as NUMBER.

I debugged the code and realized that when pattern is applied `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation` is used to match. Hence in the case when `£20.49` is the input `£` is the value of `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation` and `#` is the value of `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TextAnnotation`.

Is there an environment setting to change this behavior?

Sample rule

```
# make all patterns case-sensitive
ENV.defaultStringMatchFlags = 0
ENV.defaultStringPatternFlags = 0

# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

normalizedValue = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NormalizedNamedEntityTagAnnotation" }

{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: (([{word:"#"}]) ([{ner:"MONEY"}])), action: (Annotate($1, ner, "IGNORE"), Annotate($2, ner, "NUMBER"), Annotate($0, normalizedValue, "TOKENS_REGEX")), result: "NUMBER" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the latest version on GitHub or version 3.9.2.  Currency is no longer normalized, so the pound sign will no longer be turned into "#" by default.

You should be able to do something like

```
originalWord = { type: "CLASS", value: edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation }
```

Then you can replace `word` in your rule with `originalWord` .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. That worked.
But is there any env setting to use  `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation` instead of `edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$OriginalTextAnnotation` ?

Comment: You can create a variable for that class (as you did with normalizedValue).  Then you can match on that in the pattern.  Instead of word use your variable name.